# Como compilar o SQLite3?

Tags: c, sqlite, thread, cmake

Estou tentando rodar um pequeno teste com SQLite3. Não consigo rodar este programa tão simples! Já pesquisei soluções na internet e nenhuma delas resolveu meu problema. Segue o programa, *cmakelists* e *logs*:

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

int main(void)
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   int rc;

   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return 0;
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return 1;
}
```

E o seguinte **CMakeLists.txt**

```
find_package(Threads)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(Testes)

add_definitions(-Wall -g -o -std-c11 -lpthread -lcppdb_sqlite3 -ldl)

add_executable(Testes main.c)

add_library(sqlite3 sqlite3.c)

target_link_libraries(Testes sqlite3)

target_link_libraries(Testes ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})

target_link_libraries(Testes ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

**CMakeError.log**

```
Determining if files pthread.h exist failed with the following output:

Source:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>


int main(){return 0;}
```

Comment: Porque colocou `#include <pthread.h>` no código?

Comment: Achei que fosse necessário por causa do sqlite. Mas retirei e ainda tenho erros. E dois deles são justamente a respeito dela.

-- Looking for include file pthread.h - not found
-- Could NOT find Threads (missing:  Threads_FOUND)

Comment: Tira tudo que se refere a *threads* do *script*. O SQLite pode até trabalhar com elas, mas nem é recomendado. Se se for fazer isto, tenha certeza que domina o assunto, é muito fácil errar. Compile assim: `gcc -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 main.c sqlite3.c -ldl` Se ainda quiser usá-la tente compilar só com isto `gcc main.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl`. O `main.c` seria o seu código.

Comment: Não tenho palavras pra descrever o quanto estava perdida por conta disso! Muito obrigada. Isso resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução é mais simples que isto. Uma compilação simples resolve o problema:

```
gcc main.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl.
```

O `main.c` seria o seu código.

Mas nestes caso seria até melhor não usar *threads*:

```
gcc -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 main.c sqlite3.c -ldl
```

De resto é só tirar qualquer referência à *threads*.